# Обфускация кода android

Tags: java, android, proguard

Собираю приложение, подписываю апк релизным ключом, копирую на телефон, при установке вылетает ошибка "Приложение остановлено". 
Что делать не знаю.

Код из gradle:

```
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
        }
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn org.springframework.http.converter.**
-dontwarn com.androidquery.auth.**
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice**
-dontwarn org.springframework.http.client.**
```

Comment: можете попробовать получить стактрейс используя `ACRA`. Или еще раз прочитать требования proguard у используемых библиотек

Comment: @metalurgus не совсем понял "требования proguard у используемых библиотек".

Comment: У некоторых библиотек есть свои требования к обфускации. Например, когда они используют рекурсию, и какие-то классы ищут по имени класса, они требуют оставлять имя этих классов неизменным. И их создатели выкладывают текст, который нужно обязательно добавлять в proguard.properties, чтобы библиотека работала

Comment: сборка без обфускации работает? Вы уверены что в ней проблема? Можно посмотреть stacktrace только нормальным путем(не ACRA)

Comment: @metalurgus `когда они используют рекурсию`, Вы наверно хотели сказать `рефлексию`? а то я как то не уловил мысль)

Comment: @ermak0ff, точняк, заработался я вчера, конечно `рефлексию`.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean без обфускации все в порядке

Comment: Хорошо бы приложить лог, что бы видно было на что именно он ругается. А так можно использовать -keep class com.google.**
-keep class android.support.** и так далее.